# What does empty .forRoot() exactly do in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, routes, ng-modules

I've seen people using  *.forRoot()* in their projects along with the main forRoot(paths inside...)  which brings them to the sub-url.

What is the purpose of this empty for root?

Example (it is used in the imports of the defined Module):

```
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    ShareButtonsModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`forRoot` is a convention for static class methods on modules.

It is used to keep certain providers of the module as **singletons**, meaning they are only injected into the **main app module** and not into individual components.

This way, you can use `MyModule.forRoot()` **only** in the main app module, and still import `MyModule` into components that need it.

The data that is passed inside of `forRoot(...)` depends on the module itself and the providers it has. Whether `forRoot` is empty or takes parameters, the point is that it is used **only in the main app module**.

[Here is a good article discussing forRoot() in detail.](http://angularfirst.com/the-ngmodule-forroot-convention/)